# How exactly do you use Rack's env hash?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, file-upload, rack

I have a Rails 4.2 app with a heavy file upload traffic.

I want to override `rack.multipart.tempfile_factory` in order to provide additional behaviour associated with the temporary files Rack creates under the hood when accepting file uploads.

So where and how do I change Rack's `env` hash **exactly**? Tried doing `env['...'] = ...` inside an initializer, said `env` is undefined. Changing it to `ENV` raises an error saying it cannot convert a lambda to String (`rack.multipart.tempfile_factory` requires a lambda so I can't just change it to a String). Using `request.env` inside a controller method has no effect whatsoever. I tested the last by copy-pasting the stock Rack factory's one line of code and added writing a random number to a file with a fixed path; that file never got created in the first place after uploading a few files, so there you go.

I am looking for an official solution and don't have the intention to monkey-patch Rack. Its spec states this is possible, so how exactly should I be doing it?

Of course, if all else fails, I will resort to hacking, but I'd prefer to hear the official ways of doing it first.

*(And while we're at this, can you also recommend a gemless solution to override `rack.hijack_io`, with some real-world examples? Searching for that thing in particular wasn't very helpful, nobody seems to provide an end-to-end working solution, only bits & pieces).*

Thank you for your consideration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Part 1: How to modify Rack's `env`

You just need to override `Application#call`. In `config/application.rb` (or `config/environments/production.rb` if you like) you add this method:

```
class Application < Rails::Application
  ...
  def call(env)
    env["rack.multipart.tempfile_factory"] = ->(what, now) { "lambda time" }
    super(env)
  end
  ...
end
```

See [#call](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Application.html#method-i-call) for more info on that.

### Part 2: The meaning of `ENV`

`ENV` is a constant in Ruby that corresponds to the shell environment. This allows you to do things in your shell script like:

```
$ export MY_VAR=hahahaha
...
irb> ENV['MY_VAR'] #=> "hahahaha"
```

It's more than a Rack variable—it's a Ruby constant!

Your error "cannot convert lambda to string" is because all `ENV` values must be Strings. So even if you do

```
$ export MY_VAR=42
```

You'll get

```
irb> ENV['MY_VAR'] #=> "42"
```

where `"42"` is a String, not an Integer.

Comment: I knew I was being stupid, it's just one of those days where you get so pissed off you can't figure out something that simple by yourself that you get even more pissed off and thus lose all ability to actually solve it. Thanks a lot.

RE: Part 2, I knew what ENV was, I was just so frustrated that decided to give it a shot (knowing full well it won't work, lol).

Thanks for your comprehensive answer. I owe you 20 beers.

Comment: no worries, I figured as much—but just wanted to add Part 2 for completeness. It was fun digging, cause I haven't really gotten into that side of Rails too far myself.